# Check all radio controls with a specific substring on an ASP.NET form

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I'm working on a .NET-powered questionnaire which contains several repeater controls, each row of which contains three radiobuttons. I'm trying to write a simple Javascript function to check all the controls on the page which contain the word "chkGreen" in the control name/id.

The page looks something like this:

```
Repeater 1
Description 1           ( ) Green ( ) Yellow ( ) Red
Description 2           ( ) Green ( ) Yellow ( ) Red
Description 3           ( ) Green ( ) Yellow ( ) Red

Repeater 2
Description 1           ( ) Green ( ) Yellow ( ) Red
Description 2           ( ) Green ( ) Yellow ( ) Red
Description 3           ( ) Green ( ) Yellow ( ) Red
```

Here's the function so far:

```
   for (i = 0; i < document.Form1.elements.length; i++) {
      var _control = document.Form1.elements[i].id
      if (_control.indexOf("chkGreen") > 0) {
         eval(_control.checked = true);
      }
   }
```

This function does not work. When I add a document.write or alert() to the statement, it properly fires, so the logic is apparently working, it's just the actual radiobutton check code is not working.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to eval the _control.checked line.

```
for (i = 0; i < document.Form1.elements.length; i++) {
  var _control = document.Form1.elements[i]; // EDIT: you want the element, not the id of the element
  if (_control.indexOf("chkGreen") > 0) {
     _control.checked = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response. I tried the function without using eval() and it didn't work. I have since gotten the function to work by using document.getElementById:

```
for (i = 0; i < document.form1.elements.length; i++) {
  var _control = document.form1.elements[i].id
  if (_control.indexOf("chkGreen") > 0) {
    var thecontrol = document.getElementById(_control);
    thecontrol.checked = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: argh...I missed the .id you were putting at the end of the var _control line. Edited.